# How to Encrypt data in JMeter script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am writing a simple script in Jmeter to pass username and password to the logging page of a website. I want password to be encrypted but I am not sure if Selenium Webdriver API provide any functions to encerypt data before passing it into the sendKeys() function.

Here's what my script looks like:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('url')
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium, org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
var wait = new pkg.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)
var user = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('userName'))
user.sendKeys(['username])
var pass = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('password')) 
pass.sendKeys(['password'])
```

PS: I know the approach to pass data from CSV but that's not exactly encryption.

Comment: Not entirely sure why it's important. Usually you'd give the test a locked down test account. Besides, encrypting something isn't giving you the security you might think - your test still needs to decrypt it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. That said, is there a way to do so?

Comment: What does the website expect?  You can encrypt any data you want by including the encryption jar in jmeter lib/ext folder, importing it from a beanshell, then calling the methods in the class from the beanshell code.

Comment: Do you know the specific encryption type?

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar that contains the encryption algorithm in jmeter/lib.

Suppose this class is in class com.foo.utils.encryption.EncryptionUtils, you would do:

```
 var pkg = JavaImporter(com.foo.utils.encryption)
 var encryptUtils = new pkg.EncryptionUtils()
 vars.put("result", encryptUtils.method(inputString));
```

You can then use the ${result} variable.